Mysql increment field didn't work property with mybatis plus
1.entity
public class SaledData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @TableId(value = "id", type = IdType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate recordDate; // has unique index
    ...
}

2.fetch data from remote then save to mysql db
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1/1 \* \* ?") 
public void getSaledData() {
    @Resource private ISaledDataService iSaledDataService;
    SaledData saledData = new SaledData();
    ...
    iSaledDataService.save(saledData); 
    // sometimes has repeated data will intercept by unique index 
}

3.wrong id's result
        "id": 158,
        "createTime": "2024-05-13T04:00:08",
        "recordDate": "2024-05-12"

        "id": 160,
        "createTime": "2024-05-12T20:00:12",
        "recordDate": "2024-05-11"

How does it happen? I am confused.

It isn’t clear to me what problem you’re asking about.  Is it that there is no ID 159? Is everything else working as expected? There are various reasons why sequences can skip numbers, and it doesn’t necessarily indicate a problem. It’s best not to rely on sequence IDs being contiguous. Is that what you’re asking about or is it something else?

The latest date's id is smaller than old date

Is that actually unexpected? How are the dates set? There isn’t really enough information in the question for anyone to be able to help.

entity:
private LocalDateTime createTime;

Scheduled:
SaledData saledData = new SaledData();

saledData.setCreateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
...
iSaledDataService.save(saledData);

